# set a key without value for a dictionary in python

Tags: python

I am trying to set a dictionary for the staff's salary in Python.  I want to create two functions, `getname()` and `getsalary()` so I tried:

```
empDic={}

def setname(n):

empDic={'n':''}
```

And then in python interactive 2.7 I typed:

```
>>>setname('marson')

>>>print empDic

{}
```

The result is still an empty dictionary, How can I deal with that?

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. In any case, the empDic inside the function will create a  local variable. To use/update the global one, you need to use the `global` keyword. Also, dictionaries with only keys are usually a sign that you need `set`s instead.

Comment: Not sure the dupe is a great fit for this, using global is not going to work and there are more things wrong in the OP's code than scope issues

Answer (score 2):

You would need to modify the original dict:

```
empDic={}

def setname(d, n):
   d[n] = ""

setname(empDic,"marson")

print(empDic)
{'marson': ''}
```

You are creating a new local variable `empDic` in your function, you are also using a string `"n"` not the name `n` passed in to the function.